# Get a sum of column values based on a time range on Power BI or Query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

I want to create a column which sums all of the breakdown time which occurs in a given time range.[This is the table I want to add the column to. The breakdowns occur in within the Actual Shift Start and Actual Shift End time range.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AM43F.png)

[This table has the breakdown time and I have a separate column which calculates the amount of time in minutes the breakdown happened for.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNY5y.png)

I want to add a column which sums all of the minutes of breakdown time which happens on that day in the range given in the first table.

I'm not really sure how to attempt this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.